# WordPressで本文のpやhタグにclassをつけたい

Tags: wordpress

WordPress の

```php
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

で出力された p, h2, h3 にclassをつけたいです。

```html
<p class="my-class-name">あいうえお</p>
```

みたいにしたいという事です。

body要素に異なるクラスを追加することは見つけたのですが、本文に追加する方法がわかりません。教えてほしいです。

[body_class() | Function | WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/#Add_Classes_By_Filters)

Answer (score 1):

**the_content();** の代わりに **get_the_content();** で本文の内容を取得し目的のデザインに編集すると良いと思います。
以下str_replaceを使った簡単な例です。

```
$content_string = get_the_content();

$content_string = str_replace('<p','<p class="classname" ',$content_string);
$content_string = str_replace('<h2','<h2 class="classname" ',$content_string);
$content_string = str_replace('<h3','<h3 class="classname" ',$content_string);

echo $content_string;
```

Comment: `the_content()`内では`get_the_content()`の他に`the_content`フィルタと`]]>`の置換が行われていることに注意してください。 https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/#source

Comment: @yyz
ありがとうございます
post-template.phpを編集することで、実行できました